# Decorator data binding

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Ich have a simple Decorator which is displaying some informations of the model. When the model changes, the frontend won't change. How can i accomplish this?

```
@Decorator(selector: '[information]')
class DecoratorA implements AttachAware{

  final dom.Element element;

  @NgOneWay('infotmation')
  DecoratorModel informationModel;
```

The Model is provided by a component. A template that will be created in the decorator.

```
  _createTemplate(){
    dom.SpanElement positionSpan = new dom.SpanElement()..appendText(informationModel.sometext);
    element.append(positionSpan);
  }
```

This is actually working but only if the content of the model isn't changing. If the Component changes the data in the Model `DecoratorModel`,  the `informationModel.someText`, which is added by the Decorator won't update in the view.

Using`{{informationModel.someText}}` will cause an error, because the component does not have a getter for it. This is correct, the Decorater has the getter.

What is the propper way for this?

Answer (score 2):

Decorators are not a good fit for this case, for the exact reasons (limitations) that you described.

Try using a `@Component` instead.